# Mixing business with pleasure

Tags: перевод, значения, сленг

Is it the same as "приятное с полезным"?

Comment: If i were trying to translate "приятное с полезным" into English, i would use the verb "combine" rather than "mix" to remove the negative connotation.

Answer (score 12):

It's not quite the same. In English-speaking world this phrase is used to describe a situation when a person actually combines his working activities and enjoyment, often with a detriment to productivity.

> **mix business with pleasure**
>  to combine work with social activities or
>   enjoyment (usually negative) *Let's keep this relationship strictly
>   professional. I prefer not to mix business with pleasure*.

[Source: Cambridge Idioms Dictionary, 2nd ed. Copyright © Cambridge University Press 2006]

While in English this idiom is usually used in a negative sense, Russian phrase `совмещать приятное с полезным` in most cases is positive and means "to organize useful activities in such a way so you can enjoy it". Useful activities also include studying, sport, healthcare etc. Also, from my observations, Russians not so often have the stereotype that work/business must not be enjoyable to a person who does it.

So, *in most cases*:
**to mix business with pleasure** - get pleasure ***instead*** of working
**совмещать приятное с полезным** - get pleasure ***from*** your job/business/any other useful activity

I think the translation `совмещать приятное с полезным` can be sometimes used for this phrase, although for most cases you should prefer something like `совмещать работу и развлечения`, which has more negative connotation.

---

On the contrary, if you are translating to English, you may try verbatim translation `to combine useful and pleasant`. It's not a common phrase, but it is grammatically correct.

Comment: спасибо, Роман, за ответ. очевидно, что это совсем разные по смыслу выражения, просто нигде не нашел ёмкого аналога "совмещать приятное с полезным" (. и продолжаю искать.

Comment: @Artemix злые там какие-то :). Спасибо.

Comment: Roman, what do you think about "deal of fun"?

Comment: @garik, думаю, это совсем не то. Кстати, вы не первый, кто интересуется этим выражением: http://www.bbc.co.uk/dna/mble/html/F2712585?thread=5023014. Гугл по запросу "combine useful and pleasant" находит некоторые результаты, однако среди них половина является такими же вопросами по правильности (возможности) употребления.

Comment: Minor note: if translating verbatim, it should be ‘to combine _the_ useful and _the_ pleasant’ — ‘useful’ and ‘pleasant’ are adjectival nouns here (just like in Russian) and need the article ‘the’.

Answer (score 3):

Самая простая конструкция, передающая смысл: "both ... and practical", где первым вставляется удобное слово согласно контексту. Прилагательные об удовольствии не подходят во всех случаях, поскольку русское выражение тоже не всегда буквально. Сегодня в моем тексте про охранные сигнализации было удобно перевести "both convenient and practical", когда речь шла об охранных барьерах, замаскированных под уличные фонари.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to translate this phrase, I have found 'to combine pleasure with utility'. I like this variant.

Answer (score -4):

а чем не устраивает "mixes business with pleasure"? Вот например http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/mix+business+with+pleasure  такое упоминает.
А приятное с полезным это примерно о том же идиома, хоть и не дословно. Но, позвольте, она и не обязана быть дословной калькой.

Comment: По вашей же ссылке и написано что в англ. языке "mix business with pleasure" это плохо. Есть много примеров когда дословно совпадающие выражения в разных языках имеют разные оттенки смысла и поэтому их нельзя использовать при переводе.